# Installing libapache2-mod-python removes cacti

Tags: server, package-management

I'm trying to install Django on a machine that is primarily a network administration box; it has nagios and cacti installed on it. I went in today to install Django, and when I followed the following instruction I got weird results:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-python
```

Told me it was freeing 77 MB worth of files. I should have taken more notice and stopped, but I assumed if apt-get wanted to do it, that it was probably OK. The next thing I see however is an ncurses based app explaining that we were now removing cacti. I hit ctrl-z, as I don't want to remove cacti. Now my system seems to be in a bit of a weird state (though cacti is still OK).  For example:

```
me@mysystem:~$ sudo dpkg -l|grep -v "ii"
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Cfg-files/Unpacked/Failed-cfg/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                            Version                         Description
+++-===============================-===============================-============================================
rF  cacti                           0.8.7e-2                        Frontend to rrdtool for monitoring systems a
rc  cacti-spine                     0.8.7e-2build1                  Multi-Threading poller for cacti
rc  libgd2-noxpm                    2.0.36~rc1~dfsg-3.1ubuntu1      GD Graphics Library version 2 (without XPM s
```

Also, I'm seeing lots of these errors now (as expected, I suppose):

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

What's my best next step? I don't want to lose my cacti config for sure. What's the best way to go about cleaning up this system?

Comment: You shouldn't loose the configuration file unless you run `apt-get purge [package]`

Comment: OK ... are you suggesting I let it remove cacti and then manually re-add it?

Comment: This question might relate to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cacti/+bug/544828

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading that correctly, the first step would be  `dpkg-reconfigure cacti`.

This may or may not work- I'm assuming the configs somehow got munched during the install.

I just installed libapache2-mod-python on this machine and did  `aptitude why-not cacti` and got "Unable to find a reason to remove cacti." This is a bit odd, as cacti is not installed.

Result of  `aptitude install cacti` after installing the above:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information
Initializing package states... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2-mpm-prefork{a} cacti dbconfig-common{a} libapache2-mod-php5{a} 
  libdbd-mysql-perl{a} libdbi-perl{a} libhtml-template-perl{a} 
  libnet-daemon-perl{a} libphp-adodb{a} libplrpc-perl{a} 
  mysql-client-5.1{a} mysql-client-core-5.1{a} mysql-server{a} 
  mysql-server-5.1{a} mysql-server-core-5.1{a} php5-cli{a} php5-common{a} 
  php5-mysql{a} php5-snmp{a} rrdtool{a} snmp{a}

The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apache2-mpm-worker{a}

0 packages upgraded, 21 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Need to get 33.2MB of archives. After unpacking 86.6MB will be used.

I don't understand why aptitude want to remove mpm-worker if it doesn't detect it as a conflict (via aptitude why-not). Do you still have mpm-worker installed?

Comment: apache2-mpm-worker and apache2-mpm-prefork are packages that are mutual exclusive, i.e. you can only have one version installed. Since the package you install depends on apache2-mpm-prefork, it will installed, hence apache2-mpm-worker must be removed.

Comment: I've also recently installed moodle, btw which might be confusing things.  OK ... I have a backup of this machine, so I'll try the reconfigure.

Comment: Package: apache2-mpm-prefork
State: not installed

Comment: Whoops, I commented before I understood what txwikinger was talking about. Yes, from the package states readout above, cacti depends on mpm-prefork, which, as txwikinger points out, conflicts with mpm-worker (I'm taking your word for this, aptitude why-not apache2-mpm-prefork does not make this obvious). Nice catch, sir.

Comment: me@mymachine:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure cacti
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: cacti is broken or not fully installed

Comment: me@mymachine:~$ sudo dpkg -l |grep mpm-worker shows no results, seems like its not installed.

Comment: Ok, I'm thinking it might be instructive to have a look at your /var/log/apt/history.log in order to ascertain what those packages were that were removed when you installed libapache2-mod-python.

Comment: If dpkg-reconfigure says that cacti is broken or not fully installed, I recommend trying apt-get --fix-broken (or Fix Broken Packages from Synaptic's Edit menu, if you have a gui). If that doesn't work, then you might try removing and then installing the package. DO NOT use apt-get --purge for this: As Jorge Castro points out above, that's how you zap the configs when you want to, which you don't.